# Sqlite running perfect on emulator but not working on mobile device

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using **SQLite** as in my android project and it's working fine while running on **Emulator**, but as I install the application using the **USB device** on my **android phone** it's not even letting me to login showing an error that I implemented for wrong username or password.

Here is the code for DatabaseHelper in which i am using functions for insertin data to database and selecting from database. **usernamepassword** function is for selecting users from database.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Khataapp.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "users_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "USERNAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "PASSWORD";
    public static final String COL_4 = "ROLE";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT, ROLE INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table products (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, PRODUCT_TITLE TEXT, PRODUCT_PRICE TEXT, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION TEXT, PRODUCT_IMAGE BLOB)");
    }
//insert data
    public boolean insertData(String username, String password,final int role){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,username);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,password);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,role);
        long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

//    select username password
    public boolean usernamepassword(String username, String password)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from users_table where username=? and password=?",new String[]{username,password});
        if (cursor.getCount()>0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

//    add products
   public void insertProducts(String pTitle, String pPrice, String pDescription, byte[] pImage){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO products VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

       SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
       statement.clearBindings();

       statement.bindString(1, pTitle);
       statement.bindString(2, pPrice);
       statement.bindString(3, pDescription);
       statement.bindBlob(4, pImage);

       statement.executeInsert();
   }

   public Cursor getProducts(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
        return database.rawQuery(sql,null);
   }

    public Cursor getData(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
        return database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    }

}
```

Login activity

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button login_btn;
    EditText et_username,et_password;
    DatabaseHelper mydb;
    Session sessionManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        sessionManager = new Session(this);

        login_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        et_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String username = et_username.getText().toString();
                        String password = et_password.getText().toString();
                        Boolean chkuser = mydb.usernamepassword(username,password);
                        if (chkuser == true){
                            sessionManager.createSession(username);
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Login.this,
                                    MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"username or password is incorrect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the app from the device and rerun?

Comment: @forpas Yes I just tried to reinstall the app after uninstalling the app... but still it didn't work. :(

Comment: In `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);` you use version 2. This means that you made changes to the database, right? Also does your app crash? If so post the error log. If not, how do you save the user's name and password? Are you sure that the values you search for exist in the table?

Comment: version 2 was for the new table that I created for products, and yes database has the values, first sign up to the system with 3 different usernames and as I mentioned its working properly on emulator.

Comment: but i never run the version 1 on the mobile... could that be the issue?

Comment: Obviously the code you posted is not all the code, so anything could cause the problem.

Comment: @forpas i just edited the post with all the code... please have a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working perfect try this

```
// call below class from activity or fragment
    DBClass dbClass=new DBClass(getActivity());
    dbClass.insertData("abc","xyz","student");


public class DBClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Khataapp.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "users_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "USERNAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "PASSWORD";
public static final String COL_4 = "ROLE";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION      = 3;

public DBClass(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " +
            COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL_2 + " STRING, " +
            COL_3 + " STRING, " +
            COL_4 + " STRING" + ")";

    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
}


//insert data
public boolean insertData(String username, String password,String  role){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,username);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,password);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,role);
    long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    Log.d("val_result",""+result);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

 // user login
  public boolean userLogin(String username, String password)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where "+COL_2+"=? and "+COL_3+"=?",new String[]{username,password});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
        Log.d("val_", "success");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for your reply but i just tried to change to uppercase, and still not its not letting me login.... and the one with lowercase was running nice on emulator.

Comment: still no result :(

Comment: already did it... its all the code that you can see above... just the issue is i think SQLite is not connecting on mobile device.

Comment: Actually i updated the onupgrade function to create new table